# Instantiating generic's parameter

Tags: java, generics

I'm learning Java's generic, I snag into some problem instantiating the type received from generic parameters (this is possible in C# though)

```
class Person { 
    public static <T> T say() {
        return new T; // this has error
    }
}
```

I tried this: [generics in Java - instantiating T](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173844/generics-in-java-instantiating-t)

```
public static <T> T say(Class<?> t) {
    return t.newInstance();
}
```

Error:

```
incompatible types
found   : capture#426 of ?
        required: T
```

That doesn't work. The following looks ok, but it entails instantiating some class, cannot be used on static method: [Instantiating generics type in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434041/instantiating-generics-type-in-java)

```
public class Abc<T>
 {

    public T getInstanceOfT(Class<T> aClass)
    {
       return aClass.newInstance();
    }      

}
```

Is this the **type erasure** Java folks are saying? Is this the limitation of type erasure?

What's the work-around to this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You were very close. You need to replace `Class<?>` (which means "a class of any type") with `Class<T>` (which means "a class of type T"):

```
public static <T> T say(Class<T> t) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
    return t.newInstance();
}
```

Comment: +1 and accepted, not as elegant as C# though (not your fault ;-) ). Btw, is this what they called type erasure, that's why it cannot instantiate a T directly?

Comment: @Hao: exactly: the actual type of T is not available at runtime, that's why you need to pass in a Class object to make it explicit.